# Now.sh deployment is not working with GitHub

Tags: github

Question is related to [Now.sh](https://zeit.co/now) server.

Usually, when I create are PR on GitHub, `Now` deployment happens automatically. But suddenly it stopped working and getting the message on PR.

> This branch has not been deployed
>   No deployments

My latest changes which might cause the problem are:

- I upgraded the plan yesterday.
- Then I downgraded it for some reason.

Already tried the following things:

- Tried to push more changes for testing.
- Create another PR and commit some changes.
- Tried with another project. Did not work either.

Here is PR: https://github.com/princesodhi/boiler-with-react-next-ts-express-now/pull/10

Any ideas on how I can resolve this?